# Compare character by character of strings from an array efficiently

Tags: c, dictionary, graph, adjacency-matrix, adjacency-list

```
  Palavras = (char***)malloc(maxLen*sizeof(char**));
     matrizAdj = (int***)malloc(maxLen*sizeof(int**));


 for(i=0; i<maxLen; i++){
    Palavras[i]= (char**)malloc(NMax_Palavras[i]*sizeof(char*));
    matrizAdj[i]=(int**)malloc((NMax_Palavras[i])*sizeof(int*));
    Palavras_Atuais[i]=0;
   }

for(i=0; i<maxLen; i++){
  for(j=0; j<NMax_Palavras[i];j++){
  Palavras[i][j]=(char*)malloc((i+1)*sizeof(char)+1);
  matrizAdj[i][j]=(int*)malloc((NMax_Palavras[i])*sizeof(int)+1);
}
}

 rewind(fpIn1);
   while(fscanf(fpIn1, "%s", novaPal1) == 1){
    size_t len = strlen(novaPal1);
    strcpy(Palavras[len-1][Palavras_Atuais[len-1]], novaPal1);
    Palavras_Atuais[len-1]+=1;
   }
for(i=0; i<maxLen;i++){ /*different array according to word length*/
  Palavras_Atuais[i]=0; /*index in the string array according to the length*/
      for(k=0;k<NMax_Palavras[i];k++){ /*NMAX_palavras stands for the number of words of that particulary length*/
        Palavras_Atuais[i]=aux3; /*initializes in 1 so it dont compare with it self*/
        while(Palavras_Atuais[i]<NMax_Palavras[i]){/*while you dont compare with all the words*/
      
          for(j=0;j<i;j++){
              if((Palavras[i][k][j])==(Palavras[i][Palavras_Atuais[i]][j])){ /*compare 1 one with all oders*/
                  continue;
              }
              else{
                 matrizAdj[i][k][Palavras_Atuais[i]]+=1; /*create an adjacency matrix with the number of different characters*/
                 matrizAdj[i][Palavras_Atuais[i]][k]+=1;
              }
              
          }
          Palavras_Atuais[i]+=1; /*go to the next word*/
      
}
aux3+=1; /*add on in each cycle meaning that it doesnt compare words that already been compare since the matrix will gonna be symetric*/
}
}
```

Hello, based on a given dictionary with words of various sizes I need to code a weighted adjacency matrix based on the number of different characters.

Later I have saved and organized all the words in n matrix (n=word size), which in the code is Palavras[i][k].
My code works for small dictionaries but as the size increases (for example if it has 200 000 words) as the complexity is n^2 it doesn't work.
Any tips on how to do this more efficiently?

Comment: What exactly does "it doesn't work" mean? Does it take an unacceptably long time to finish execution? Or does your program crash?

Comment: it crash when the dictionary is too big.

Comment: Im sorry for that. I edited so now it has the malloc for the words and matrix

Comment: If you have 200 000 words, then you need a square matrix with the dimensions 200000*200000, which is 40 billion. Assuming that every field of the matrix is an `int` of 4 bytes, that means that the memory requirement is 160 GB (!). This probably means that `malloc` is failing. You should always check the return value of `malloc` and print an error message if it fails, instead of letting the program crash.

Comment: Yeah it so much space, i dont know what to do about that. is there any way to make an adjacency matrix using less memory? Or should i use an linked list

Comment: That depends on what exactly you want to accomplish. If you have one word and you want to store the number of different characters with all other 199,999 words, then you will need 800 KB of data. If you want to do this for all 200,000 words instead of a single word, then you will need 200,000 times that amount, which is 160 GB of data. This assumes that you are using a 4-byte `int` to store the number of different characters. However, a 1-byte `unsigned char` would probably be sufficient, because it is guaranteed to be able to store numbers from `0` up to `255`. So you only need 40 GB of data.

Comment: It is certainly possible to handle 40 GB of data, but when handling such large amounts of data, that data should be in a file on secondary storage (i.e. on a hard disk or an SSD), not in main memory.

Comment: However, I suspect that you may be asking about an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Why exactly do you want a matrix storing the number of different characters for all pairs of words? What is the actual problem that you are trying to solve? Maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: What do you want to do here?  Perhaps you are building a spellchecker that offers suggestions for the true word the writer was trying for?  In which case, an adjacency matrix of true words is not needed, since you need to build on the fly a list of true words that are close to the misspelled word.